# ADF Mapping Data Flow byNames expression exception

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory(ADF) Mapping Data Flow byNames expression is throwing an exception in the derived column block. Actually I need to access multiple columns values in a single derived column.

```
toString(byNames(['parent', 'child']))
Exception: DF-TX-115 - Variable results are allowed in assignments - EXE-0001,[390 436 536 677],
           Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#bynames

Comment: can you show us the source schema?

Comment: I am using Schema drift & auto mapping, thus schema will be evaluated at run time. Also, I will be passing columns ['parent','child'] using a parameter.

Comment: Can you please try `array(byNames(['parent','child']))` or `toString(array(byNames(['parent','child'])))`? Just from the data flow, the example is the first one. it all works well.

Comment: Another question, does the derived column 'test' mapping to the sink table column 'test'?

Comment: Hi @hagarwal, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the expression and  get the same error:
[image]

Just from Data Flow, we could use bellow expression to achieve that:

[image]

1. `array(byNames(['parent','child']))`
   [image]
2. `array(parent,child)`
   [image]

toString function only can convert a primitive datatype to a string, I think that the reason which cause the error.

Comment: Thanks @LeonYue array(byNames(['parent','child'])) worked as expected.